# Devise routes do not skip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need some help here.

I'm trying to eliminate the route paths destroy and cancel from the Devise registerable module but I haven't been succeed.

Route.rb

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations], controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions',
  confirmations: 'users/confirmations',
  passwords: 'users/passwords'
}

get '/users/sign_up', to: 'users/registrations#new'
get '/users/edit',    to: 'users/registrations#edit'
post '/users',        to: 'users/registrations#create'
put '/users',         to: 'users/registrations#update'
```

Model.rb

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

Rails route

```
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)         devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)        devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /users(.:format)                devise/registrations#update
                                      PUT    /users(.:format)   devise/registrations#update
                                      DELETE /users(.:format)   devise/registrations#destroy
                                      POST   /users(.:format)   devise/registrations#create
```

As you can see in Rails routes, Devise is creating the route paths `devise/registrations` even when set the option `:skip` up for the `devise_for` method. Someone already face this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Along with skip also add skip_helpers: true.

skip_helpers: skip generating Devise url helpers like `new_session_path(@user)`.
This is useful to avoid conflicts with previous routes and is false by default.
It accepts true as option, meaning it will skip all the helpers for the controllers
given in :skip but it also accepts specific helpers to be skipped:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations, :confirmations], skip_helpers: true
devise_for :users, skip_helpers: [:registrations, :confirmations]
```

Source: 
From devise Documentation
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L160